# Parallel copying of folders in IOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, file-io, uikit

I am trying to copy 2 folders located at:

```
foo/a
foo/b
```

to

```
bar/a
bar/b
```

I need the main thread to be blocked until both the folders are copied.
Also I would like to not perform file i/o on the main thread.

One way to do this would be to block until foo/a is copied to bar/a and then copy foo/b to bar/b.

I am thinking of instead having 2 NSOperations and parallelizing the operations. Would this method have any advantages? In other words are file operations serialized on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

> Are file operations serialized on iOS?

If they are on the same thread, yes. However, Apple encourages you to use multiple threads for file operations. From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html):

> Because file-related operations involve interacting with the hard disk
>   and are therefore slow compared to most other operations, most of the
>   file-related interfaces in iOS and OS X are designed with **concurrency**
>   in mind.

and specifically about `NSFileManager`

> For most tasks, it is safe to use the default NSFileManager object
>   simultaneously from multiple background threads.... You should then
>   use your unique instance from one thread at a time.

So it's fine to do your copying on different threads in parallel.

> Would parallelizing two NSOperations have any advantages?

Yes. One that comes to mind is if one folder is a large, low-priority folder, and the other is a small but critical folder. You could execute both on background threads, but give a higher thread priority to the critical copy operation.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance if I've missed the point:

Given that on iOS there is almost certainly one single file system, I'm not sure that you will see any real speed up by executing two directory copies in parallel. It's the same Flash chips, the same memory bus, etc. Having two parallel copies going on at once isn't going to make those single things run any quicker than if you had one happening after the other. There's nothing about the hardware that will benefit from two separate CPU threads running it.

The only thing that two parallel copies would improve on is the CPU time needed to drive the FS, but that is definitely not going to be the bottleneck in an iOS system.

If you don't want your main thread blocked whilst this is going on, I think you would be better off using async I/O. I don't know what iOS offers in that line, but I'm sure there will be some async I/O API available. Alternatively you could have a single background thread doing all the directory copying sequentially, allowing the main thread to do whatever it needs in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute multiple I/O operations asynchronously. So, you would receive some advantages from running the copying as parallel operations. You can explicitly lock out certain files, but by default all thread have the same access abilities as the main process ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2)) and nothing is preventing them from accessing files in parallel (i.e. I/O operations are not serialized). You can take a look at the [*Concurrency Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information on file access with concurrency.

To further elaborate, file I/O in most systems are not very protected processes. Given the level of abstraction a developer works with in iOS/OS X programming the difference in hardware is basically irrelevant as far as file accessing goes. Files are not really protected in this sense. For example, you can have two threads accessing the exact same file and if not handled well can easily destroy that file ([more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH11-SW1)).

#### Original Answer:

This covers more implementation level details.

In this situation I would recommend just using a single operation queue and having a non-one concurrent operation limit. If you take a look at the docs for [maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperationQueue/maxConcurrentOperationCount) you will see that the default value for an operation queue's concurrent operation count is `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount`, meaning that a queue will attempt to execute as many parallel operations as possible.

This is obviously great for blocks that are not dependent on each other (thus needing to be run synchronously), and by default this behavior should work great for you out of the box.

As far as UI Blocking goes. You should be able to add your queued copying operations via [addOperations:waitUntilFinished:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperations:waitUntilFinished:) and just pass `YES` in for the `waitUntilFinished:`. This will block the current thread, so just add the blocks on the main thread and the UI will be auto-blocked for you. Then once all the operations are completed (even if they are running async) the main thread will open up again. Pretty slick.

Comment: Honestly curious about the down vote. Is there something incorrect with my answer or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: This answer just adds more implementation detail as to the problem I described but does not answer the question in itself. My question was if this method (parallelizing file i/o) has any advantages over executing the file i/o operation one after the other.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification comment. I updated my answer, I hope that helps more. Please let me know I am missing something.

Comment: I know that nothing is preventing me from parallelizing it. But can you add more detail onto the lower level implementation details of file i/o. e.g. Does it matter on SSD devices?

Comment: I added another paragraph to (hopefully) help answer your last questions. I know you knew you could parallelize the operations, but you asked if there were any advantages and if I/O was serialized. I made sure to directly answer both of those questions in the first paragraph for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of ways to do that, but I don't understand why you would like to block the main thread until the copy is done even if you want to make the copy off the main thread.
In my opinion the best way to achieve that, is blocking that UI with a progress/activity view, so the user can't press anything on the UI, for the copy I can think about those options:

- NSOperationQueue with dependency between the 2 copy operation (created by subclassing NSOperation) if you want that one starts once the other is finished and register your class as observer for the `-operationCount` property on `NSOperationQueue`,when the count reaches 0 you can "turn on" the UI. I think that is too much for just this two operations. GCD will decide in which queue they will run.
- Use a `dispatch_semaphore_t` and just launch the copy methods inside a normal `dispatch_async` on a particular queue. More info [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63338/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-2).
- Use a serial queue and GCD, use the already provide serial queue `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, 0)`. Then call a dispatch_async passig that queue adding 3 blocks, the first copy, the second copy and the "turn on" of your UI. Here are guaranteeing the serial execution of the operations in the same order that you have added.
- Use GCD dispatch_group, create a group and add you copy blocks pointing them to run on another queue than the main, then you can be notified when those have finished and "turn on" the UI.More info [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/).
- Use `dispatch_write` with semaphore because dispatch write is a very efficient async call.More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948903/dispatch-write-and-dispatch-read-usage).

Those are some ideas, but in my opinion the faster to implement is a dispatch_group. Remember that queue are a different concept from threads.
File system is single and shared I don't think that you will any particular gain of speed running them in parallel, In my experience I've found faster running writing and reading files operation in sync, this due probably to the overhead of async calls and because there is only one resource. A very efficient way to write and read files on iOS are the dispatch_io functions but they can  be overwhelming.
In my opinion is useful to use async calls if you want that the user continues to use your application while the files are copied, but since you want to block the UI, it can just be useful to show a progress bar and you can achieve that by using a simple serial queue with callbacks launched on the main queue to update the UI.